# Approximating a 1-d Kalman Filter with non-Gaussian Observation Noise

Tags: bayesian, kalman-filter, filter

I'm looking for a Bayesian filter where observations are generated according to $s_t = \gamma s_{t-1} + w_p$ and $w_p \sim Normal(0, \sigma_p^2)$. Both $\gamma$ and the variance of the process noise $\sigma_p$ are known. However, different from the classical Kalman filter, the observational noise is not assumed to be Gaussian. **Is there a specific name for this kind of filter?**

I'm particularly interested in comparing the Kalman filter's estimates to the optimal estimates for a problem where the observation noise is only approximately Gaussian. Hence, I tried to recursively compute the posterior (numerically) using simple grid approximation, but I'm struggling with the marginalisation part:

$$p\left({s}_{t} \mid {m}_{1: t-1}\right)=\int p\left({s}_{t} \mid {s}_{t-1}\right) p\left({s}_{t-1} \mid {m}_{1: t-1}\right) {d} x_{t-1}$$

How would something like this look with a simple grid approximation? **Is it feasible?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recall any specific for the kind of filters you mentioned. Suppose that your likelihood model at hand is student-t, then just search student-t filters. There is no need to come up with a generic term.

Solving filtering problems with non-Gaussian measurement noises is very common. The most well-known solution is particle filters. Another solution is to approximate your measurement model with a Gaussian one by moment matching.